# Generate new variable from observations in multiple variables

Tags: stata, reshape, data-management

I have an example dataset with the variables `date`, `spx` (market price), `trans_1` (stock 1 price) and `trans_2` (stock 2 price):

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input int(date spx) double(trans_1 trans_2)
14610 100     1    1
14611 102   1.1   .9
14612 103  1.21  .81
14613 104 1.321 .729
end
format %tdnn/dd/CCYY date
```

I need to rearrange the data so that I derive three variables: `trans_id`, `date` and `trans_price` where every date in the dataset exists for every stock id and all stock prices are combined in a `stock_price` variable.

Expected outcome:

```
   date   spx   trans   trans_id

1/1/2000   100         1         1 
1/2/2000   102       1.1         1 
1/3/2000   103      1.21         1 
1/4/2000   104     1.321         1 
1/1/2000   100         1         2
1/2/2000   102        .9         2
1/3/2000   103       .81         2
1/4/2000   104      .729         2
```

I have read through various forums trying to make use of the `xpose`, `merge` or `append` commands, but could not come up with a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
generate id = _n
reshape long trans_ , i(id) j(_j)

drop id _j
bysort date (spx): generate id = _n

sort id (date)

list, sepby(id)

     +------------------------------+
     |     date   spx   trans_   id |
     |------------------------------|
  1. | 1/1/2000   100        1    1 |
  2. | 1/2/2000   102      1.1    1 |
  3. | 1/3/2000   103     1.21    1 |
  4. | 1/4/2000   104    1.321    1 |
     |------------------------------|
  5. | 1/1/2000   100        1    2 |
  6. | 1/2/2000   102       .9    2 |
  7. | 1/3/2000   103      .81    2 |
  8. | 1/4/2000   104     .729    2 |
     +------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi there, many thanks for the solution as well as your help! Works for me as well!